# how to get download link after upload photo to firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, storage

[image: error screenshot]

I tried to get a download URL like this but it is not getting correct URL. I am a beginner in Firebase, how can I do it?

Comment: try getting image using image name.? 
again run a listener and get url of that image.?

Comment: Thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the download URL like this

```
fileRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {

     @Override
     public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        final Uri download_url = uri;
     }
}):
```

Comment: Thank you very much,,,, It working well :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can get your download path *after* uploading the file as follows (you need to call a second method on your reference object (`getDownloadUrl`):

```
    profilePicUploadTask = fileRef.putFile(imgUrl).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)
        {
             // note: you can get the download path only after the file is uploaded successfully. 
             // To get the download path you have to call another method like follows:
             fileRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() 
             {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) 
                {
                   // uri is your download path
                }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. But it also not working :-( can not put putFile to profilePicUploadTask

Comment: @Sampath see my edited answer. You need to use `fileRef.putFile()` and `fileRef.getDownloadUrl()`

Comment: yes.. thank you very much! :-)